# How to keep Windows 7 CSC Service from running down my laptop battery?

Tags: windows, battery

I've a new laptop that lasts less than an hour on battery.  I've bottomed out the culprit: cscservice.  I've been manually turning the service off then on when I'm on battery power. Cycling the trick seems to do the trick, as I get over 4 hours once I've done this.

I've been scouring the internet to figure out how to make the the cscservice more mobile friendly.  People have reported similar issues, but they tend to just turn the service off---but I would actually like to use offline files.

I found an article that suggested that a corrupt database could cause an issue.  There was a flag to set in the registry to have it rebuild the offline file database.  Unfortunately, it operates as before: CPU and disk usage that quickly drains my battery.

I've gone through and setup a schedule for offline file syncing which has options to only run when on wall power and to only sync at 2am.  But for some reason cscservice still runs, although the Sync Center doesn't show it's activity swish.

Anyone have an idea how to fix the issue?

Thanks,

Mark